# EXCEL - lookup max value in range if the cell column beneath is marked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im having a problem that I need help to solve - anybody ? (:

I need to look up the max value in a row, if there is any marking in the column in the row beneath.

Can anyone help ?

Im using EXCEL2010 if it does any matters.

The best wishes from
Dalgaard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "any marking", assuming you want the max value in row 1 where row 2 has **any** entry you can use an "array formula" like this:

`=MAX(IF(2:2<>"",1:1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If you want to be more specific e.g. max value in row 1 where row 2 has value "x" then you can easily change that to

`=MAX(IF(2:2="x",1:1))`

Comment: Thanks Barry ! It was exactly what I wanted... Why should I confirm it with ctrl+shift+enter ?

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` is always required for array formulas - basically any formula where you are asking a function (like IF here) to look at a range instead of the single value it normally expects - see Chip Pearson's explanation here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx